# systemctl services + how to un-limit StartLimitBurst

Tags: shell-script, rhel, services, systemctl

we defined the following details in our service

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StartLimitInterval=400
StartLimitBurst=5

RemainAfterExit=no
LimitNOFILE=60000
```

the details defined that service will start automatically 5 times ( StartLimitBurst=5) in case service will stop

is it possible to `un-limit` the service , so it will start ***every time*** ( ***without any limit*** ) in case service is stooped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current settings, if the service runs successfully for 400 seconds, then the 5 times limit is reset and you will have the full 5 restarts available again.

But if you want to, you can disable the limit mechanism by setting `StartLimitInterval=0`. Then `systemd` will keep attempting to restart your service without limiting the number of attempts. There will still be a 10-second delay between server stopping and the next restart attempt, as defined by `RestartSec=10`.